# add anchor tag if content have some particular tags

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to add anchor tag in few texts if article page returns some specific tags.

For example I have this article page.

> some dummy paragraph here India Russia Serbia paragraph content

Tags of this pages are **India, Serbia**

So, I want to add anchor tag to India and Serbia in this content (

> some dummy paragraph here India Russia Serbia paragraph content

). I have tried this below code, but it add the anchor tag on last tag (**Serbia**)

```
$tags = array();
$tag_row = array();
foreach($article_tags as $tag)
{   
    $tag_row['text'] = $tag['tag_name'];
    $tag_row['url'] =  asort_get_url(ARTICLE_BASE_URL,$tag['tag_url']);
    array_push($tags,$tag_row);
    
    echo $tag_row["text"]; // but this line returns IndiaSerbia
    // detect tag links in content and add anchor tag   
    echo $article_content_with_tags = preg_replace("/(".$tag_row['text'].")/i","<a href=".ARTICLE_BASE_URL."/".$tag_row['url']."><b>$1</b></a>",$article_content);
}
```

Comment: Can't get what you actually needed

Comment: i want to highlight or add <a> tags in some particular words of a content or article page

Comment: `echo $tag_row["text"]; // but this line returns IndiaSerbia` then you have a problem earlier in your processing.  I've voted to close this page as Off-topic.